# How to add custom URL parameters to WMTS connection in ArcObjects SDK for ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, wmts

I am trying to add a WMTS layer to ArcMap with the ArcObjects SDK. The layer adds just fine however the tile calls will not go through because the call ArcMap is constructing do not contain the api token necessary for the calls and I can not figure out how to add them. WHen creating the server connection manually there is a spot for customer paramters, when adding them manually the server conneciton works propery. How do I add those custom parameters in ArcObjects? No matter how I try to add them with SetProperty() none of those parameters are honored in the tile calls.

```csharp
private void formLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string accessToken = "token";

            //// Get a reference to the active map document
            IMxDocument mxDocument = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
            IMap map = mxDocument.FocusMap;
            string url = "https://url/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&" +
                "REQUEST=GetCapabilities&maxar_api_token=" + accessToken;

            // Create a property set to hold the WMTS connection properties
            IPropertySet connectionProps = new PropertySetClass();
            connectionProps.SetProperty("URL", url);
            
            WMTSConnectionName conName = new WMTSConnectionNameClass();

            conName.ConnectionProperties = connectionProps;
            IWMTSServiceDescription WMTSServiceDescription = conName.OpenEx(null) as IWMTSServiceDescription;
            if (WMTSServiceDescription == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not connect to WMTS service.");
            }
            connectionProps.SetProperty("LAYERNAME", "DesiredLayer");
            conName = new WMTSConnectionNameClass();
            conName.ConnectionProperties = connectionProps;
            IWMTSLayer newLayer = new WMTSLayerClass();
            if (newLayer.Connect(conName as IName) == false)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not create WMTS item");
            }
            newLayer.TileMatrixSet = "EPSG:3857";
            IPropertySet dimProps = new PropertySetClass();
            dimProps.SetProperty("format", "image/png");
            dimProps.SetProperty("access_token", accessToken);
            dimProps.SetProperty("foo", "bar");

            newLayer.Dimensions = dimProps;
            ILayer layer = newLayer as ILayer;
            layer.Visible = true;
            layer.Name = "Maxar:Imagery";
            ILayerPosition layerPos = layer as ILayerPosition;
            layerPos.LayerWeight = 230;
            Debug.WriteLine("101");
            map.AddLayer((ILayer)newLayer);
            mxDocument.ActiveView.Refresh();


        }
```